# Streaming Vs Downloading Site Load Speed debate

Tags: seo, performance, page-speed, google-pagespeed

We have a number of sites that use bg video - currently the video file (1.4mb) is loaded from the server and increases page load.

My question is whether streaming the video on loop via Vimeo or similar would improve the load speed as the video is no longer a page asset?  can anyone offer any advice please?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it probably will speed things up. As things are, various elements on your page are probably kept waiting while the video loads. Professional platforms like Vimeo (I think) and Wistia (definitely) will load the video asynchronously, so the hit to your page load time is minimized.

This way all your server has to load are the on-page elements, which no longer include the video, but do include an iframe link to Wistia/Vimeo/etc. You may notice a particularly impressive speed increase for mobile users.

As with any such changes, you should test this sort of thing on one page before rolling it out across all of your sites. Use [Pagespeed tools](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/?hl=en) to assess the impact, as what has a huge impact on one site may not on another.

Comment: This only solves the piping of resources, this could just as well be done by controlling your resources in a manner that the video will load last, this doesnt answer the difference between stream and download